# Lint error with snackbar extension function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-snackbar, android-lint, kotlin-extension

I have the following extension function to reduce a bit the code and to avoid forgetting the duration when showing a snackbar:

```
fun Fragment.showSnackbar(text: String, length: Int = Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT) {
    view?.run { Snackbar.make(this, text, length).show() }
}
```

But the lint is giving me the following error:

```
Error: Must be one of: BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE, BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_SHORT, BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_LONG or value must be ≥ 1 (was -1) [WrongConstant]
       view?.run { Snackbar.make(this, textResId, length).show() }
                                                  ~~~~~~
```

It seems that if you pass a custom length param it should be an int >=0 and it is detecting that the default param is a custom one not a system/class one but it is (LENGTH_SHORT, which is -1).

If the length param is of type `BaseTransientBottomBar.Duration` (which is an interface notation to set the possible values of the length param) it compiles well but I don't know how to assign it as a default value.

There is any way to avoid the lint error or to set a default value of type `BaseTransientBottomBar.Duration`?

--- EDIT: after apply the @rahat approach:

```
fun Fragment.showSnackbar(text: String, @BaseTransientBottomBar.Duration length: Int = Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT) {
    view?.run { Snackbar.make(this, text, length).show() }
}
```

The error:

```
   [PATH]/DesignExt.kt:18: Error: Must be one of: BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE, BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_SHORT, BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_LONG [WrongConstant]
   fun Fragment.showSnackbar(text: String, @BaseTransientBottomBar.Duration length: Int = Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT) {
                                                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Lint doesn't complain for me for this function, using the latest jetpack libraries and build tools. I'm using `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2` and `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1`.

Comment: I tried the answer from @rahat but still happening

Comment: From my experience, with IntDef type annotations, this isn't usually a problem. Lint only complains if you pass a hard-coded value directly to such a function. Are you using the latest Kotlin version 1.4.21, and latest libraries I commented above?

Comment: @Tenfour04 nop, I'm using android plugin 3.5.3 and androix core 1.0.2 but I can't upgrade them now. The strange thing is that sometimes it doesn't show the error, but the most of times it does.

Comment: Finally I avoid the error adding the warning 'WrongConstant' to the lint.xml file. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65907919/888900

Comment: Unfortunately this is a known (and still open) [issue.](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/504)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I avoid the error adding the warning 'WrongConstant' to the lint.xml file. If it was the only thing in the file it will be:

```
android {     
  lintOptions {          
      warning "WrongConstant"      
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the signature of the called method is as follows

```
@NonNull
  public static Snackbar make(
      @NonNull View view, @NonNull CharSequence text, @Duration int duration)
```

and the class `Snackbar`

```
public class Snackbar extends BaseTransientBottomBar<Snackbar>
```

finally the signature of `Duration` is

```
@RestrictTo(LIBRARY_GROUP)
  @IntDef({LENGTH_INDEFINITE, LENGTH_SHORT, LENGTH_LONG})
  @IntRange(from = 1)
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
  public @interface Duration {}
```

So the value passed must be one of the values from the `Duration`, even if it is, the lint is coming because the parameter is not annotated and can accept any `Int` value, but when you annotate then when you call your method with a value different than those present in `Duration` it will give you warning at that place, and it **may** lead to **RuntimException** if passed value is not one of them.

Try with this,

```
fun Fragment.showSnackbar(text: String, @BaseTransientBottomBar.Duration length: Int = Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT) {
    view?.run { Snackbar.make(this, text, length).show() }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but still happening... thanks in any case.The strange thing is that sometimes the linter doesn't show the error, but the most of times it does

Comment: Lint coming even after annotating your method?

Comment: Yes, still happening @rahat

Comment: let me know the lint you are getting

Comment: I added it in the original post